# Firebird DDL + DML statements within a transaction

Tags: c#, transactions, firebird

Is there any way to do the following in Firebird within a transaction?

```
 CREATE TABLE a (INTEGER c1);
 INSERT INTO a (c1) VALUES (1);
 DROP TABLE a
```

If not, why not?

Any workarounds? Tried savepoints, ADO.NET transactions, nothing seems to work.

**UPDATE** 
Firebird transactions do not mix DDL and DML statements very well. You can create tables but they will not be visible within the transaction. Two separate transactions are needed (or no transaction at all). Also, don't bother with anonymous transactions or execute blocks as they don't seem to work over the wire.

Comment: The questions are why do you want to do this? And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @JensH: as a substitute for variables as they are unusable over the wire which executes single statements at a time. Execute blocks don't seem to be supported either, and even if they were, the 64k limit renders it unusable.

Answer (score 4):

Firebird does not support using a table in the same transaction it was created. Also I don't see the point of what you are doing here (creating, filling and dropping a table). Maybe instead you are looking for the [Global Temporary Table](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-ddl-table.html) functionality of Firebird: You define the table once (eg with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`), and then you can reuse its definition without having to recreate the table every time.

As you comment that you want to use this table *to store "variables"*, you could also look into the use of [`RDB$SET_CONTEXT()`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-set_context.html) and [`RDB$GET_CONTEXT()`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-get_context.html) (Firebird 2.0 and higher), which allows you to store values in a connection or transaction context.

For example this will set a variable `VariableName` to a (`VARCHAR`) value '513'

```
select rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'VariableName', 513) from rdb$database
```

You can then retrieve it using:

```
select rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION', 'VariableName') from rdb$database
```

If you need it as an `INTEGER` you will need to add an explicit cast.

Comment: Temp tables are still subject to this limitation. DDL + DML statements are not really mixable in a Firebird transaction it seems. The purpose of the table is to store "variables" so they can be used over the wire.

Comment: But a Global Temporary Table can be defined once, and then reused by all users (with rights to it) and all connections, but the content is only visible to a single connection.

Comment: Also I think that _"The purpose of the table is to store "variables""_ is very significant to the question, because that can lead to an entirely different answer: use `RDB$SET_CONTEXT()` and `RDB$GET_CONTEXT()`

Comment: @MarkRoteveel: Tried that already. Context variables are limited to 1000 per session and limited to varchar(255). I need more than that.

Comment: @HermanSchoenfeld Then use the GTT as I suggested, if that won't work for you, then explain why you can't use it.

Comment: @MarkRoteveel: I'm using a temp table already, I just wanted to create, insert, select and drop it within 1 transaction. This turns out to be impossible within a single transaction.

Comment: You do realise that the content of a GTT is only visible to the same transaction (or connection; depending on the `ON COMMIT` clause) that added the data, if so what is the added value of dropping the table?

Comment: to not leave dangling tables in the database.